# Selecting children of a child in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a side nav that is importing the complete site nav and I'd like to cut it down to only child links of the current section. Structure is this:

```
<div class="sidebarLinks">
<ul>
    <li> <!-- MAIN NAV SECTION -->
        <a href="#" id="MainA">MainA</a>
    </li>
    <li> <!-- MAIN NAV SECTION -->
        <a href="#" id="MainB">MainB</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="B-A">B-A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="B-B">B-B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="B-C">B-C</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li>
    <li> <!-- MAIN NAV SECTION -->
        <a href="#" id="MainC">MainC</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="C-A">C-A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="C-B">C-B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="C-C">C-C</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So if I'm on B-A, I want to see B-A, B-B and B-C in the side nav, but not MainB or any other links. I've tried the following, but it returns the second child of every main nav section (B-B, C-B, etc.):

```
$(".sidebarLinks ul li:nth-child(2)").children().show();
```

Any tips are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".sidebarLinks > ul > li:nth-child(2) > *").show();
```

The [jQuery child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) is the ">" character. You can also save the call to .children() with "> *" as that will get any element that is a child of the nth li.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Parrots. I hadn't thought of using "*" to reference all children. I got it to work with this:
`$(".sidebarLinks ul li:nth-child(3) li").children().show();`
This also worked:
`$(".sidebarLinks > ul > li:nth-child(2) li > *").show();`

Thanks for the help.